# Регулярное выражение NotePad++ убрать первое число в скобках

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

как регулярным выражением в NotePad++ убрать первое число в скобках?

Вот такие вот строчки

```
(648, 505, 92),
(748, 305, 928),
```

Нужно добиться

```
(505, 92),
(305, 928),
```

Не знаю правильно или нет, но решил так

```
\(\d\d\d,
```

Замена на

```
\(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

**Найти**:       `^\h*\(\d+,\h*`
**Заменить на**: `\(`

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\h*` - 0 и более горизонтальных пробельных символов
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `\d+` - одна и более цифр
- `,` - запятая
- `\h*` - 0 и более горизонтальных пробельных символов.

В шаблоне замены символ `(` экранирован, так как в Notepad++ в шаблонах замены возможно использование условий, которые задаются с помощью круглых скобок, в значит, символ `(` (и `)`) является "специальным" и подлежит экранированию.
См. настройки и пример использования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]